# How to query with muti-level json in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, jsonq

I wanna make a search function to search some data in a json.

the json is like this:

```
{"type1":{
        "pd1":{
             "price":"110","detail":{
                          "QAQ":{"a":"0","b":"0","c":"0","d":"0"}},
                          "TATTT":{"QwQ":"0","TwT":"0","QAQ":"0","TAT":"0"}}},
"type2":{
        "pd2":{"price":"50","detail":{"d1":{"w1":0,"w2":0}}},
        "pd3":{"price":"10","detail":{}}}}
```

example:

search("110")

I expect get

```
{"type1":{"pd1":{"price":"110","detail":{
"QAQ":{"a":"0","b":"0","c":"0","d":"0"},
"TATTT":{"QwQ":"0","TwT":"0","QAQ":"0","TAT":"0"}}}}
```

search("pd3")

get

```
{"type2":{"pd3":{"price":"10","detail":{}}}}
```

and then

search("w")

get

```
{"type1":{"pd1":{"price":"110","detail":{"QAQ":{"a":"0","b":"0","c":"0","d":"0"},"TATTT":{"QwQ":"0","TwT":"0","QAQ":"0","TAT":"0"}}},
"type2":{"pd2":{"price":"50","detail":{"d1":{"w1":0,"w2":0}}}}}
```

try to use Jsonq,but not success

```
$jsonq = new Jsonq();
    $jsonq->json($json_data);
    $res = $jsonq->where("price",'=',"110")
    ->get();
dump($res);
#retuen only []
```

Maybe Jsonq can only search one level.

I don't know how to make json neat on stackoverflow QAQ

Comment: Is `Jsonq` necessary to use or any routine accomplishing the task would do?

Comment: no it just a try

Comment: how does `search("w")` returns data i don't see any indexes with w. how do you wanna search?

Comment: I wanna it like to do this job "SELECT * FROM xx WHERE yy like '%w%'"

Comment: @Sam You need to store these details in a database with proper columns. Storing in JSON format isn't recommended, but here are some json functions if you are using MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: @vivek_23 I use json format store data ,because the data can expansion... maybe like type1 type2 type3 type4...type99  pd1 pd2 pd3.. pd100.  I don't konw how to store data in mySQL with dynamic columns...

Comment: @Sam What's the max number of columns you could have?

Comment: @vivek_23 theoretically unlimited . Practically  type<20,production under type <100,detail under production<10 ,item under detail<10

Comment: In this job,users can edit their menu. They can add many type for their productions, then add productions under the type.The productions maybe have some detail ,like size,color,etc

Comment: @Sam technically I would have a separate table for productions, type and detail and  have a pivot table to have the IDs of the respective attribute against a user ID. If this is too complicated, then you could store it as JSON for now and use json functions in MySQL for the search.

Comment: @vivek_23 Too complicated... I will try the functions in MySQL ,thank you very much